# what is $(123)(341)(15)$ as a product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory

My answer was: $(13)(12)(31)(34)(15)$

but $(13)$ and $(31)$ are equivalent so is the final answer

$(13)(12)(34)(15)$?

if not how do you do this?

Comment: The first two cycles are permuting $1$. They are not disjoint.

Comment: Most pairs of cycles in your answer are not disjoint.

Comment: It looks like you misread the question. It did not ask you to convert the permutation to pairs that you swap. You are allowed (in this case actually required) to write longer cycles, but each cycle must not touch any elements touched by any other cycle. That’s what “disjoint” implies in this context.

Comment: Non-disjoint cycles do not commute in general, so your idea that you can cancel $(13)$ and $(31)$ is mistaken: the cycle $(12)$ is in the way and prevents the simple cancellation since you cannot just commute either of the other cycles with it.

Comment: $(13)(31)=(), $ not $(13)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheap, easy way to do this is to compute the actual permutation and then look at its disjoint cycles. That will always work.

We can have a little fun doing cycle manipulation instead though using the identity $(abc) = (ab)(bc)$.
$$\begin{align}
(123)(341)(15) &= (231)(134)(15) \\
&= (23)(31)(13)(34)(15) \\
&= (23)(34)(15)\\
&= (234)(15).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(123)(341)=(234)$.  I can multiply them first by associativity.  So we get $(234)(15)$.